# NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID error when running VueJS project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an year old VueJS project that runs on v3.9.2 of @vue/cli-service. I have been running it on `https://localhost:8000` using the `--https` flag of `vue-cli-service` command.

Now, I updated my `@vue/cli-service` package to v3.12.1. When I run `npm run serve`, I get the following error in Chrome. There is no button to proceed to localhost.
[image: Chrome error message]

Can anyone tell me what has changed in Vue cli service that this error is showing up and how can I fix this error?

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "generate": "babel-node --config-file ./generator/babel.config.js -- ./generator",
    "prod-serve": "npm run generate && vue-cli-service --mode production --https --port 8000 serve",
    "build": "npm run generate && vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "lint-check": "vue-cli-service lint --no-fix",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service --https --port 8000 serve --host localhost",
    "postinstall": "postinstall",
    "test": "jest --changedSince=master --coverage",
    "test-ci": "jest --ci",
    "test-watch": "npm run generate && jest --watch --no-coverage",
    "test-e2e": "cypress run --browser chrome",
    "test-e2e-headless": "cypress run",
    "test-e2e-dev": "cypress open"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0-rc.1",
    "can-ndjson-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "color-convert": "^2.0.0",
    "filesize": "^4.1.2",
    "intro.js": "^2.9.3",
    "jsonpath": "^1.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "luxon": "^1.11.4",
    "papaparse": "^4.6.3",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "search-query-parser": "^1.5.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.21",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.8.1",
    "vue-introjs": "^1.3.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue2-dropzone": "^3.5.2",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
    "vuetify": "^2.1.12",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-i18n": "^1.11.0",
    "vuex-router-sync": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "3.12.1",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^4.0.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "cypress": "^3.4.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "fs-extra": "^8.0.1",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest-junit": "^6.4.0",
    "postinstall": "^0.4.2",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.1",
    "sass": "^1.23.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
    "worker-loader": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 10"
  ],
  "postinstall": {
    "generator/acl_actions.csv": "link public/acl_actions.csv",
    "generator/acl_fields.csv": "link public/acl_fields.csv"
  }
}
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Same thing happens if I create a fresh project as well.  Both new and old projects work in Firefox.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @stellr42 Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: There was an issue with certificates on Mac with older versions of webpack-dev-server (which vue-cli runs under the hood). See [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2273). Not sure if this applies to Linux but can you try updating vue-cli to the latest version, where this issue was fixed?

Comment: I updated to the latest vue-cli version, but, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bug was introduced in webpack-dev-server version 3.9: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2313

I managed to use the older version without the bug by adding to dependencies:

```
"webpack-dev-server": "3.8.2"
```

And changing the version of @vue/cli-service in devDependencies (note the tilde)

```
"@vue/cli-service": "~4.0.0",
```

Then removed node_modules, package-lock before doing `npm install` and `npm run serve`

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 3):

IF certification error is triggered from browser not reaching a valid signature in that machine, try generate a new one:
[How to create a self-signed certificate with OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl)

other possibility is to make Chrome ignore absence of certifications:
in **Chrome address bar** :

> chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

(answer from: [technipages](https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-bypass-your-connection-is-not-private-message) )